# Culture Independent IsVowel

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, localization

I need to create a function that will tell me if a character is a vowel or a consonant but I need it to be culture independent.  In other words, using a string with "aeiou" isn't good enough because some languages use other vowels such as those with accents.  Do I have to compile a list of all unicode characters that could be vowels or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I reckon you'll have to make a list...

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant

Comment: If you removed the accent would testing for aeiou be enough?

Comment: Somehow reminds me of yesterday's The Daile WTF: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Too-Much-of-a-Bad-Thing.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Very few languages have a one-to-one match between characters and sounds to begin with. Take iota - some will pronounce the first i as a vowel, others as a consonant.

The phonetic alphabet is supposed to help with this. See for instance:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet

You would have to use the phonetic alphabet as an intermediary, and take the vowels from there. Then, however, you still have the problem of translating words into that phonetic alphabet. Some online dictionaries may be able to help you with that, but even then the same word will likely appear multiple times sometimes with different pronunciations, and I don't know if there are any that allow you to hook up through a webservice or if there are any offline options.

http://www.photransedit.com/online/text2phonetics.aspx (example with horrible full-screen ads)

This problem borders on the complexity of translation software, where you would really need some understanding of the context to understand which word you even need to look up and in what database.

So depending on your requirements, you may want to start as simple as you can, but take the above into account. To allow your application to gain precision later on, you could start with making a function that returns the IPA vowels, and then make a lookup table for letters and letter combinations matches them. Then later on you can look towards getting or creating better data.

You can use charts like these as input:

http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-soundsipa.htm

Many language training books also have an overview. I've always liked the 'Teach Yourself ... ' series, as they always have an overview of the sounds of a language.

Comment: Wanted to take a moment to thank you for your help.  I ended up sticking with just the standard English vowels including y ('aeiouy').  Your answer was very informative and has actually helped me in some other non-related pursuits.